# Caching Jar dependencies for Maven-based Docker builds

Tags: maven, docker, dependencies, dockerfile

I'm building a Docker image from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.3-jdk-8
MAINTAINER Mickael BARON  

ADD pom.xml /work/pom.xml
WORKDIR /work
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline --fail-never

ADD ["src", "/work/src"]
RUN ["mvn", "package"]
```

With this Dockerfile, I force to download the dependencies before packaging my Java project. Thus, I don't have to redownload the dependencies every time I changed a file from my src directory.

But, there is a problem and this problem is depending on the version of Maven (base image). In fact, the dependencies are downloaded but they are not persisted into the ~/.m2 directory of the container. It's empty. Thus, when I change some source file all the dependencies are redownloaded.

However, I noticed that if I change the version of Maven from the base image (for example `FROM maven:3.2.5-jdk-8`), it works.

Very strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new instruction regarding this topic:
https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven#packaging-a-local-repository-with-the-image

> The $MAVEN_CONFIG dir (default to /root/.m2) is configured as a volume so anything copied there in a Dockerfile at build time is lost. For that the dir /usr/share/maven/ref/ is created, and anything in there will be copied on container startup to $MAVEN_CONFIG.
>
> To create a pre-packaged repository, create a pom.xml with the dependencies you need and use this in your Dockerfile. /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml is a settings file that changes the local repository to /usr/share/maven/ref/repository, but you can use your own settings file as long as it uses /usr/share/maven/ref/repository as local repo.

Comment: This sorta works but has limitations, one of them is that resolving dependencies before hand does not always download all of them: [Go-offline does not find module dependencies in multi-module build.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-516)

Comment: I also found that specifying the local repo like `mvn install -Dmaven.repo.local=/usr/share/maven/ref/repository` is faster than not doing it `mvn install`. I'm not sure why this is the case, since it seems that the official docker-maven image does configure the local repository. Anyway, those are my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's because of this `VOLUME` instruction they've added:

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blame/8ab542b907e69c5269942bcc0915d8dffcc7e9fa/jdk-8/Dockerfile#L11

It makes `/root/.m2` a volume and thus any changes to that folder made by build steps are not brought on to the following build containers.

Comment: Started using a previous version without the `.m2` volume and it works

Comment: Here's an issue tracking various people's complaints about how the `VOLUME` instruction works: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3639#issuecomment-229490630